# the Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the 1st Kind

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I need to do integration

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-z~\text{cosh}(2u)-\frac{1}{y}u^2}~\text{M}\bigg(-\mu,\frac{3}{2},2z~\text{sinh}(u)^2 \bigg)~ \text{sinh}(2u)~\text{sin}\bigg(\frac{\pi u}{y} \bigg)du $$

where
$\text{M}(a,b,c)$ represents the Confluent Hypergeometric function of the the 1st kind.

The simulation is implemented using R, and M(a,b,c) is computed by the function 'kummerM' of R's package fAsianOptions. My question is how to define the upper limit for integration, here it is $\infty$ in the formula.

Assuming 
$ \mu =-0.75,z=0.5$ and $y = 0.15$.
If upper=1000, sinh(1000)=Inf; if upper=100, R crashes before obtaining the result. R can produce the results only when upper limit $\in [1,50]$. What is a 'reasonable'choice of upper limit? Although R can produce result when upper limit $\in [1,50]$, the results are quite different. The best upper limit should be the largest one?

Comment: Please see the edited post. @Claude Leibovici

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a suggestion, not a complete answer.

Have you tried substituting $\operatorname{sinh}(u)=x$? This way you mitigate the effect of the exponential growth of $\operatorname{sinh}$ to a certain degree.

This wikipedia helps you do the necessary computations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Derivatives
You might also need $\operatorname{sinh}(2x)=2\operatorname{cosh}(x)\operatorname{sinh}(x)$.

On the other hand are you even sure this integral converges? $M(a,b,c)$ does grow exponentially in $c$ and then you plug in the exponentially growing function $\sinh$, which makes it even worse. I am not sure if $e^{-\frac{1}{y}u^2}$ can dampen the resulting effect.
Here is another wikipedia to underline the exponential growth:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Asymptotic_behavior

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am not good at math. I learnt this formula from a scientific paper and going to use it to compute some results for my paper. @humanStampedist

Comment: Can you give a reference for this paper?

Comment: here is the link: https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/index_files/GJH%20-%20SABRMassZero.pdf       You may see my question concerning one part of eq(2.5) on page 4.

Comment: There is a typo in your formula. You have written $e^{-z\cos(2u)}$ but the original paper says $e^{-z\cosh(2u)}$. This term could be enough to dampen the exponential growth of $M$.

Comment: You are right! Here is a typo. But in my R code, it is cosh.@humanStampedist

Comment: A silly question, $sinh(u)^2$=$sinh(u)*sinh(u)$, right? @humanStampedist

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks! Then, the best choice of the upper limit should be 50? @humanStampedish

Comment: To be honest, I do not know. Maybe you can use the asymptotic formula given in the above wikipedia article to replace $M$ for values above $50$. That way the integrand should simplify a lot.

Comment: I appreciate your advice :)